# Why doesn't Settimeout pull the updated image URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby

I'm using Aviary to edit images online. Typically I have a local file that I click on, edit and save.

Once I save it, the image's `src` path changes from the local "uploadedimage.jpg" to a long temporary URL like:

```
http://featherfiles.aviary.com/2013-07-01/kvs78lgyil6sxlc5/69318ad57a1d490d8215cc1097cf6c32.png
```

I'm trying to have JavaScript get the updated URL once the edit is done. I tried setting "settimeout" parameters however it still keeps grabbing the original local URL of the image.

```
<!-- Load Feather code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://feather.aviary.com/js/feather.js"></script>

<!-- Instantiate Feather -->

<script type='text/javascript'>
 var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
   apiKey: 'apikey',
   apiVersion: 2,
   tools: 'all',
   appendTo: '',
   onSave: function (imageID, newURL) {
       var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
       img.src = newURL;
setTimeout(function(){fillform()}, 5000);
 },
   onError: function(errorObj) {
       alert(errorObj.message);
   }
   });
   function launchEditor(id) {
   featherEditor.launch({
       image: id
   });
  return false;
   }
</script>


<div id='injection_site'></div>
<%= form_for @post, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
<img id='image1' <%= image_tag @post.productimage_url.to_s %>
<% end %>
<!-- Add an edit button, passing the HTML id of the image and the public URL of the image -->
<p><input type='image' src='http://images.aviary.com/images/edit-photo.png' value='Edit photo' onclick="return launchEditor('image1');" /></p>



<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
var bob = document.getElementById('image1').src;
var fillform = function ()
{
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("textbox1").value=bob}, 3000);
}
</script>

myformfield: <input type="text" name="name_textbox" id="textbox1" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely because:

```
var bob = document.getElementById('image1').src;
```

Is making a *copy* of the string.  Thus, when you run:

```
document.getElementById("textbox1").value=bob
```

You're using the string as it was when it was originally defined.  You might want to change your callback to:

```
setTimeout(function()
   {
      var bob = document.getElementById('image1').src; // Get current value
      document.getElementById("textbox1").value=bob
   }, 3000);
```

You could then also get rid of the global *bob* variable.

Another way to fix it would be to change your `onSave` callback from:

```
img.src = newURL;
```

to:

```
bob = img.src = newURL; // Update bob
```